# What are near sure ways you to get moksha as quick as possible?

Tags: shiva, moksha, tara

I’m asking specifically in the Shaiva and shaktah darshanas even if a deity like Shiva,Tara or kaali bestows moksha on the Sadhaka.you can also do so by raising the kundalini with kundalini yoga or ucchishta ganapati.

Is finding a guru and doing Sadhana the easiest Quickest way to attain moksha?

Comment: Yes. Initiation from a competent guru and renunciation are the quickest and surest way. The Mundaka Upanishad III.ii.3 says "This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, he gets the Atman; unto him He discloses His glory."  He seeks those who turn their back on the world, who seek only Him.

Comment: No sadhana or Guru can grant moksha, as long there are desire of body senses. Kaivalya Moksha is rejection of body, its ego and senses and returning to original Atman state i.e. separation of Purusha/consciousness from Prakriti/matter.